# Delete control on form designer

Tags: c#, controls, designer

I was wondering what is the best way to delete an unused control (more specifically, a timer) on Visual Studio 2010. I usually go to the control in the designer and delete it from there, but the code for the control still appears on the class form. Is it safe to delete the code associated with the control too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't need the logic, then yes.  I assume you mean the handlers that are produced when you double click the control (such as `button1_Click()`).  The link to the handler is removed when you delete the control, but visual studio leaves the functions in your form class in case you are using them for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Delete a control through the visual editor, and the auto-generated code that creates the control and associates it with the form will be deleted as well. Code written by you, as well as event handling code generated through double clicking on the control or its events in the properties pane, will remain.

You should delete code that has to do with an non existent control. Any code that contains invalid references will keep you from building your application. Otherwise leftover code is just dead weight.